# Differences between System V and Posix semaphores

Tags: unix, comparison, posix, semaphore, tradeoff

What are the trade-offs between using a System V and a Posix semaphore?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From [O'Reilly](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/05/24/semaphores-in-linux.html?page=4):

> - One marked difference between the System V and POSIX semaphore
>     implementations is that in System V
>     you can control how much the semaphore
>     count can be increased or decreased;
>     whereas in POSIX, the semaphore count
>     is increased and decreased by 1.
> - POSIX semaphores do not allow manipulation of semaphore permissions,
>     whereas System V semaphores allow you
>     to change the permissions of
>     semaphores to a subset of the original
>     permission.
> - Initialization and creation of semaphores is atomic (from the user's
>     perspective) in POSIX semaphores.
> - From a usage perspective, System V semaphores are clumsy, while POSIX
>     semaphores are straight-forward
> - The scalability of POSIX semaphores (using unnamed semaphores) is much
>     higher than System V semaphores. In a
>     user/client scenario, where each user
>     creates her own instances of a server,
>     it would be better to use POSIX
>     semaphores.
> - System V semaphores, when creating a semaphore object, creates an array of
>     semaphores whereas POSIX semaphores
>     create just one. Because of this
>     feature, semaphore creation (memory
>     footprint-wise) is costlier in System
>     V semaphores when compared to POSIX
>     semaphores.
> - It has been said that POSIX semaphore performance is better than
>     System V-based semaphores.
> - POSIX semaphores provide a mechanism for process-wide semaphores rather
>     than system-wide semaphores. So, if a
>     developer forgets to close the
>     semaphore, on process exit the
>     semaphore is cleaned up. In simple
>     terms, POSIX semaphores provide a
>     mechanism for non-persistent
>     semaphores.

Comment: Performance of sem_wait()/sem_post() is generaly better when the semaphore is set in shared memory as they only call the kernel to go to sleep or to wake up. The increment/decrement part can happen without syscall. SysV semaphores ALWAYS invoke a syscall. This can make in some cases huge load differences.

Answer (score 28):

Two major problems with POSIX shared/named semaphores used in separate processes (not threads):
POSIX semaphores provide no mechanism to wake a waiting process when a different process dies while holding a semaphore lock. This lack of cleanup can lead to zombie semaphores which will cause any other or subsequent process that tries to use them to deadlock.  There is also no POSIX way of listing the semaphores in the OS to attempt to identify and clean them up. The POSIX section on SysV IPC does specify the ipcs and ipcrm tools to list and manipulate global SysV IPC resources. No such tools or even mechanisms are specified for POSIX IPC, though on Linux these resources can often be found under /shm. This means that a KILL signal to the wrong process at the wrong time can deadlock an entire system of interacting processes until reboot.

Another disadvantage is the use of file semantics for POSIX semaphores. The implication is that there can be more than one shared semaphore with the same name, but in different states. For example a process calls sem_open, then sem_unlink before sem_close. This process can still use the semaphore just like unlinking an open file before closing it.  Process 2 calls sem_open on the same semaphore between the sem_unlink and sem_close calls of process 1, and (according to documentation) gets a brand new semaphore with the same name, but in a different state than process 1. Two shared semaphores with the same name operating independently defeats the purpose of shared semaphores.

Limitation one above makes POSIX shared semaphores unusable in a real-world system without a guarantee that uncatchable signals can never be sent.  Limitation two can be mitigated by careful coding, assuming control over all code that will use a given semaphore. Frankly, its more than a bit surprising they made it into the standard as they are.

Comment: Additionally it's not easy to make POSIX semaphores recursive (as a recursive lock) and they have a strange feature, where when someone unlocks (sem_post()) a semaphore more then once (e.g. by mistake), then the subsequent lock (sem_wait()) will leave it open. A different processing: 0 - unlocked, any other then 0 - locked (with max value setting), would solve both above issues.

Comment: Semaphores are for signaling OTHER processes or threads. So, they are NOT used for locks, nor they are hold. If you want ownership semantics you have to use a mutex, not a semaphore (see pthread_mutex_t). In particular, if you want to be notified of the death of another process while holding a lock, you should mark the mutex as process shared and robust.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is old, but for the benefit of those still reading this courtesy of Google, the #1 reason I find to use System V semaphores over POSIX (system-level) semaphores is the ability to acquire the semaphore resource in a way which is automatically returned by the kernel NO MATTER HOW THE PROCESS EXITS.

I agree that the multiple (atomic) semaphore operations are rarely used (although they can be useful during staging), and that the System V interface is bizarre, but there's simply no way of reliably achieving the same clean-up semantics with POSIX semaphores.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get what you mean by "the ability to acquire the semaphore resource in a way which is automatically returned by the kernel NO MATTER HOW THE PROCESS EXITS." Can you please explain this a bit more?

Comment: @xci13: The semaphore isn't automatically released if the process is killed (e.g. with `SIGKILL`). See [iggie's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15049713/60075).

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the performances, POSIX semaphores are based on the [futex](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) under Linux. This makes them much more efficient than SYSV semaphores.
The SYSV semaphores require systematic system calls for the P()/V() operations. So, this systematically triggers user to kernel space context switches and conversely.
In the POSIX version, the underlying futex makes the caller stay in user space if there is no contention on the semaphore (the P()/V() operations are done in user space with available atomic operations). The switch into kernel mode is done only in case of contention. So, the number of user to kernel space context switches and conversely are less numerous in applications using POSIX semaphores. This makes them faster.