# ipcs -s not showing named semaphore

Tags: c, posix, ipc, semaphore

I am doing assignment in which I am using POSIX named semaphore, but it is not showing me list when I enter `ipcs -s` command.

Please help me to get entry of named semaphore. Where will I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ipcs` is for System V semaphores, you are using POSIX semaphores. For the differences, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368322/differences-between-system-v-and-posix-semaphores).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wanted to know the command to find posix semaphore in system or place where i get that.

Comment: AFIK, there is no standard to show posix semaphores at system level. For some systems, they are even shown by `ipcs`, for other systems you can use `ls /dev/shm`