# Where is POSIX named Semaphore stored?

Tags: linux, multiprocessing, posix, semaphore

A named semaphore(using `semaphore.h`) is identified by a name of the form `/somename;` that is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX-4 (i.e., 251) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are slashes.

As the name corresponds to pathname in filesystem. Where this semaphore is located?

[ipcs -s not showing named semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107716/ipcs-s-not-showing-named-semaphore)
as ipcs is for System V semaphores.How to locate POSIX semaphores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `sem_overview` man page:

> On Linux, named semaphores are created in a virtual filesystem, normally mounted under `/dev/shm`, with names of the form `sem.somename`.  (This is the reason that semaphore names are limited  to  `NAME_MAX-4`  rather  than
>          `NAME_MAX` characters.)

Do not expect this detail to be remotely similar on non-Linux systems (in fact, don't even expect semaphores to be visible by any means other than `sem_open()`).