# Equivalent of Sys V SEM_UNDO for posix semaphores

Tags: c, posix, standards, semaphore, sysv-ipc

In a Linux system with multiple processes system V semaphores allow an option of SEM_UNDO preventing a semaphore from getting "stuck" if a process holding the semaphore crashes. What is the correct method to prevent POSIX semaphores getting jammed as a result of a crash in a process holding the semaphore? Or does POSIX **guarantee** that the semaphore is freed in the case of a crash?

Comment: Is this answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053679/how-do-i-recover-a-semaphore-when-the-process-that-decremented-it-to-zero-crashe

Comment: Yes and no. I was hoping for some authoritative source on POSIX semaphores leaving things in an indeterminate state as a result of a crash. That link certainly offers a way to handle such a situation but without explaining the why / how of what seems to be an oversight from the POSIX spec. I just used SYS V semaphores in the end, but I'm curious to know why POSIX doesn't mandate what seems like the only sensible behaviour of a mutex in a crash.

Comment: Well: http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2010-01-13_PosixSemaphores/ - also using the file locking solution.

Comment: The topic is debated in answers to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368322/differences-between-system-v-and-posix-semaphores

Answer (score -1):

You can use signal handler for SIGSEGV and then do unlock and remove the signal handler.

```
// set handler
signal(SIGSEGV, handler);

void handler(int signum) {
// unlock the locked semaphores
signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_DFL);
}
```

Comment: But there's no guarantee which thread catches a SEGV. So there's no guarantee you'll be in the thread that owns the lock.

Comment: I guess semaphores have no notion of ownership, mutexes do.